# How to attach multiple files to a message in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to attach multiple files to a message in a loop.  The code below should do the following:

- open the file selector
- I would pick or more files
- the files would be sent by e-mail, to an address specified in my spreadsheet

I was able to pick one file and send the e-mail with it attached.
When I select two or more files the code stops in the following part:

```
For fichier1 = LBound(fichier1) To UBound(fichier1)
    MonMessage.Attachments.Add fichier1
Next fichier1
```

Note: I'm not using the reference of the Outlook object, because another macro stops working.

Full code

```vb
Sub Send_Email()

Dim Fichier As Variant
Dim A       As Integer
Dim MaMessagerie As Object
Dim MonMessage As Object
Set MaMessagerie = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set MonMessage = MaMessagerie.CreateItem(0)

fichier1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("File to send (*.XLS*), *.XLS*", _
               Title:="Pick at least One file", _
               MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsArray(fichier1) Then
    If fichier1 = "" Or fichier1 = False Then
        MsgBox "No file selected!", vbExclamation, "Atention"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

MonMessage.To = "myEmail@321.com"
MonMessage.CC = ""

'loop to Attach 1 or more files
For fichier1 = LBound(fichier1) To UBound(fichier1)
    MonMessage.Attachments.Add fichier1
Next fichier1

MonMessage.Subject = "Subject"

MonMessage.Body = "test"
MonMessage.Display
'MonMessage.Send

Set MaMessagerie = Nothing

'MsgBox "Email sent"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never declare `fichier1` in the code.

In the following it is declared and a new variable has been added, `idx`, that can be used when looping through the array of selected files.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SendMultiAttachmebts()
Dim Fichier1 As Variant
Dim MaMessagerie As Object
Dim MonMessage As Object
Dim idx As Long

    Set MaMessagerie = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set MonMessage = MaMessagerie.CreateItem(0)

    Fichier1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("File to send (*.XLS*), *.XLS*", _
                                           Title:="Pick at least One file", _
                                           MultiSelect:=True)

    If Not IsArray(Fichier1) Then
        If Fichier1 = "" Or Fichier1 = False Then
            MsgBox "No file selected!", vbExclamation, "Atention"
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    MonMessage.To = "myEmail@321.com"
    MonMessage.CC = ""

    'loop to Attach 1 or more files
    For idx = LBound(Fichier1) To UBound(Fichier1)

        MonMessage.Attachments.Add Fichier1(idx)

    Next idx

    MonMessage.Subject = "Subject"
    MonMessage.Body = "test"
    MonMessage.Display
    'MonMessage.Send

    Set MaMessagerie = Nothing

    'MsgBox "Email sent"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft Documentation on [For...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) Statements
The proper syntax is:

> For *counter* = *start* To *end*

Where the *counter* is a valid numeric variable.

A basic example would be :

```vb
For i = 1 to 5
```

In your code, you have the counter as an object, which is why it causes an error. If you want to iterate using an object you can try a [For Each...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) Statement.

The syntax is:

> For Each *element* In *group*

A basic example would be

```vb
Dim oItem as Variant
For Each oItem in oCollection
```

or one of my favorite uses:

```
Dim Cell as Range
For Each Cell in Range("A1:A4").Cells
```

In your code, you need to change the *element* so that it is a seperate variable because you have the same object as the *element* and the *group*.

I would suggest something like:

```vb
Dim oFile as Variant
For Each oFile in fichier1

MonMessage.Attachments.Add oFile

Next oFile
```